# Selenium WebDriver web page click event does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, dom-events

I'm using Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse with JAVA and I'm creating an automation where the initial part of the process requires user login and password, until that part I was able to do using the code below:

```
package automationFramework;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Registro {
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //º) NECESSÁRIO INSTÂNCIAR O CHROME WEBDRIVER NO INÍCIO DO PROCESSO 
    String exePath = "C:\\Users\\RAFSOUZA\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    //º) MAXIMIZA TELA E AGUARDA ALGUNS SEGUNDOS
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    //º) ABRE NAVEGADOR E VAI ATÉ O SITE ESCOLHIDO
    driver.get("https://www.credenciados.detran.rs.gov.br");
    
    //º) 1º TELA - INSERE CRENDECIAIS DO USUÁRIO    
    WebElement iptboxCred = driver.findElement(By.name("credenciado"));
    iptboxCred.sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
    
    WebElement iptboxUser = driver.findElement(By.name("usuario"));     
    iptboxUser.sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
    
    WebElement iptboxSenha = driver.findElement(By.name("senha"));
    iptboxSenha.sendKeys("XXXXXX");
    
        //Executa o Login no botão OK do site
        
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("javascript:logon();");
        }
        
   }
 }
```

When clicking the RECONET button the site opens a new tab of the Browser where the remaining data will be filled and here is where I am stuck, I can not make the code that clicks the button to open the new tab

[image]

```
<p id="menuReconet" class="menuOut" onclick="SwitchMenu('subReconet')" onmouseover="ChangeClass('menuReconet','menuOver')" onmouseout="ChangeClass('menuReconet','menuOut')">
                    <a href="redirectSng.jsp" target="_blank">RECONET</a> 
                </p>
```

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
JavascriptExecutor exeBtnReconet = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  exeBtnReconet.executeScript("document.getElementById('menuReconet').click(););
```

And I get this error in Console Eclipse:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: Is your webpage fully loaded when this click is attempted? Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: Looks like RECONET  system which is login based so more HTML would help and any error messages. And please use the snippet tool to enter html code - don't post images of the html which we can't copy.

Comment: K.Davis 
I get the following error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or 'with' block variable not set"

Comment: Put a pause in before the click. E.g. Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,3) Also, please show more of your code.

Comment: On which line do you get that error? You need to edit your question and add the error and line number and any other relevant info to investigating and solving this issue.